# Convert a URL to drive direct link and display it as image using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of multiline text:

**INPUT:**

```
Some more text here
{{image:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK/view?usp=sharing}}
Some text here
{{image:https://drive.google.com/file/d/2jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK/view?usp=sharing}}
Some more text here
```

When the js script is run it must be converted to a html with direct drive link into img tag markers

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
 Some more text here
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK" />
    Some text here
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=2jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK" />
    Some more text here
```

I have tried with:

```
htmlText = htmlText.replace(/\/file\/d\/(.+)\/(.+)/, "/uc?export=download&id=$1");
```

But how do I replace `{{image: ... }}` to `img` tags?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 capture groups for the parts that you want to keep, and match `{{image:` , `/file/d/` and `}}` that you don't want to keep.

```
{{image:(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/file\/d\/([^\/]+).*?}}
```

- `{{image:` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?:\/\/[^\/]+` Match the protocol followed by any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\/file\/d\/` Match `/file/d/`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 2
- `.*?` Match any char as least as possible
- `}}` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YDCDw5/1)

```js
const str = `Some more text here
{{image:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK/view?usp=sharing}}
Some text here
{{image:https://drive.google.com/file/d/2jYbEcuN-EMNkc0ELeVLveNJiaiuQt4XK/view?usp=sharing}}
Some more text here`;
const result = str.replace(/{{image:(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/file\/d\/([^\/]+).*?}}/g, `<img src="$1/uc?export=download&id=$2" />`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your code will not change the drive URL, please have a look at links of src tags before and after, what I asked is to acomplish both in a single regex

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird, the id will remain the same. and the url gets transformed into a direct URL

Comment: @CodeGuy I am sorry, I pasted the wrong link. I meant https://regex101.com/r/QHSep4/1/

Comment: Yes thats perfect

Comment: The trailing  /view?usp=sharing  must be removed from the src result attributes as shown in the question

Comment: @CodeGuy Ok, that was not in the expected output, but you can do it like this https://regex101.com/r/gtz3Rf/1 let me update it